# Remove meaningless words from dataframe column

Tags: python, nlp, text-processing

The dataframe column contains sentences having few three and two letter words that have no meaning. I want to find all such words in the dataframe column and then remove them from the dataframe column. 
df-

```
id      text
1       happy birthday syz
2       vz
3       have a good bne weekend
```

I want to 1) find all words with length less than 3. (this shall return syz, vz, bne) 
2) remove these words
(Note that the stopwords have already been removed so words like "a", "the" aren't existing in the dataframe column now, the above dataframe is just an example)

I tried the below code but it doesn't work

```
def word_length(text):
    words = []
    for word in text:
        if len(word) <= 3:
            words.append(word)
    return(words)

short_words = df['text'].apply(word_length).sum()
```

the output should be-

```
id      text
1       happy birthday 
2       
3       have good weekend
```

Comment: Why is *"a"* still in the expected output?

Comment: Is it good to indicate meaningless words by using the length of the characters?

Comment: @ tripleee I updated it.

Comment: @Yusufsn If you have any other efficient way to do that then I can definitely implement that too. I just thought this could be one way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You apply the fuction to a column of sequencies of words whilst the actual data is column of strings (sequencies of symbols)
You also should remove .sum() since it is totally redundant.

Rewrite the function you apply in the form:

```
 def filter_short_words(text):
    return "".join([for w in text.split() if len(w) > 3])
```

This works.

Comment: and call the function like this- `short_words = df['text'].apply(filter_short_words).sum()`? calling the function like this gives me an error - 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: No, you need not .sum() it is responsible for summation of numerical column values. Use  result = df['text'].apply(filter_short_words)

Comment: It gives me the same error list object has no attribute split

Comment: check the type of the column you apply to. if it is string (you gave an example data with string column) then my function works. if it is list (it seems that actial data is list) then remove .split()

Comment: this works...but i would need a small modification to this...is it possible to append these words to an empty list and then return that list? If so how to do that?

Comment: Words like hi, I get deleted